# How to make docky vertical?

Tags: docky

I want docky to be on the left side of the screen, not at the bottom.

Is there a theme or command line program I can use to make Docky vertical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18.04: **Show Applications** -> **Settings** -> **Dock** -> Position on screen: Left, Bottom, Right:

[image]